# Unable to simulate click action on preceding-following sibling xpath

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate a test on a mobile app, and I having trouble simulating a clicking action on an element. I use Appium Studio to record the action, then copy the codes to Eclipse for modification. In Appium Studio, the syntax for the element in question is given as:

```
driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='home_icon' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[@text='Razer Gold Mini App']]")).click();
```

However, when I copy this line over to my automation script in Eclipse, the clicking action is not simulated and the whole automation stops operating without any error message until it hit

> org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:4723 failed to respond

Probably due to inactivity.

Following is my automation script:

```
static void RazerPayPage() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Region']")).click();
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Malaysia']")).click();
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Mobile number']")).sendKeys("123456");
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='NEXT']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Log in password']")).sendKeys("password");       
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='LOG IN']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(8000);
        new WebDriverWait(driver_App, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")));
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='OK']")).click();
        driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='home_icon' and (./preceding-sibling::* | ./following-sibling::*)[@text='Razer Gold Mini App']]")).click();
```

Hope to have advice on what mistake I have commit. Feel free to let me know if further details are required.

Comment: After record, you have tried run again in Appium Studio(not in Eclipse) ? What is error also ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to send click event in this way after implicit wait :

```
driver_App.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", item)
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. May I know what arguments[0] represents and item as well ?